# Send PendingIntent and then immediately close?

Tags: android, callback, notifications, android-pendingintent

How can I close an activity launched by PendingIntent after the PendingIntent has already been sent? Is there a callback I can implement, and if so, how?

This assumes that I have no control of the activity being launched by the PendingIntent (i.e. it's the Gmail app).

Answer (score 0):

You want to close an `Activity` after sending a `PendingIntent`? If so, then just after sending `PendingIntent` add `finish();` this will close the `Activity`.